# Cannot connect to Azure SQL database, even with whitelisted IP

Tags: sql, database, azure

I am currently unable to connect to my Azure SQL database from a separate remote standalone dedicated box in a private datacenter.

I have an Azure SQL database where I manage the list of IP addresses that can connect to this database. This has worked perfectly until now. I have recently set-up a new dedicated box in a private datacenter that needs to query the Azure SQL database at regular 5 second intervals, give or take.

The problem is, this dedicated box cannot establish a connection to the Azure SQL database, despite being able to connect to other remote FTP servers, MySQL servers, etc. The Azure SQL database does have the IP address of the dedicated box on the allowed connection list. Furthermore, I temporarily opened up a massive range of allowed IP addresses (0.0.0.0 -> 255.255.255.255) on the Azure SQL database to see whether this inability to connect may have resulted from IP blocking.

Does anyone have any suggestions or thoughts on what might be causing this and how I could begin debugging the situation better?

To clarify: I can connect to the Azure SQL database from laptops with individual IP addresses in my office and elsewhere, so long as they have been added to the database whitelist; I can make outward connections to remote FTP and MySQL servers from the dedicated box; I have tried to open-up a massive range of allowed IP addresses on Azure SQL with no luck.

**Edit**

```
C:\Users\graphite.rack.ID17157>osql -S v7o06blktw.database.windows.net -U XXXXXXX@v7o06blktw -P XXXXXXX  
[SQL Server Native Client 11.0] Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a
connection to SQL Server [53].  
[SQL Server Native Client 11.0] Login timeout expired  
[SQL Server Native Client 11.0] A network-related or instance-specific error
has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not
found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server
is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server
Books Online.
```

Comment: So in other words, the problem is connecting to SQL Azure in general from the dedicated box, *not* the IP blocking?  Are you able to connect very simply, like with `osql` command-line tool or SSMS on the dedicated box to remove other variables like application errors?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages when failing to connect?  Is outpound port 1433 open?

Comment: Look at your dedicated box.  Turn off firewall and other security.  Can it connect to another SQL server box?   It might be a problem with the SQL Azure but you need to consider other failures points

Comment: and only the firewall on the dedicated box, but the firewall on the ISP for that box.

Comment: My Azure web & service roles can't connect to SQL Azure databases; I've tried republishing & whitelisting a variety of IP ranges (including 0-255) with no luck. I'm suspecting an outage is forthcoming.

Comment: @mellamokb It seems to be only when I connect to SQL Azure from the dedicated box. I can successfully connect to SQL Azure from other machines elsewhere. I have tried to establish a connection with Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, as well as a basic standard connection string from within a web app I built to test the connection.

Comment: @mcollier Yes I get a standard 'Unable to Connect' error:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

------------------------------
Error Number: 53
Severity: 20
State: 0

Comment: @Blam I have temp. turned off the basic Windows software firewall (it's a fresh install of Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2). Plus, we're talking outbound connections here anyway. I believe that there are a pair of managed Cisco asa firewalls which I do not know much about. Do you think this could be the culprit?

Comment: @JohnDandison Things seem to be fine in general with our SQL Azure database. We're in the Northern Europe datacenter. I only have this very specific problem at the moment.

Comment: @astaykov I think this is an interesting point. As outlined in my post, the dedicated box is successfully able to connect to other remote machines, such as to their FTP or MySQL servers. Does an Azure SQL connection use a specific port (1433?) that could be blocked by the pair of managed Cisco asa firewalls ?

Comment: indeed Windows Azure SQL Database (SQL Azure) works exclusively on TCP 1433 port, which is very often blocked by most of ISPs due to the SQL Warm from 2003!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To summarize.

Windows Azure SQL Database (formerly known as SQL Azure) works exclusively and only on TCP port 1433. It only support SQL Server Authentication, TCP connection and TDS protocol as of today.

In order to successfully establish connection to SQL Azure one must fulfil the following requirements:

- Create SQL Azure server & Database
- Setup SQL Azure Server's firewall rules to accept connections from the IP address of application that will connect to that server
- Make sure the box (be it Virtual, or home, or whatever) has no blocking outbound TCP port 1433
- Explicitly force encryption in connection string
- Explicitly chose to not trust server certificate in connection string

Please note that many (if not all) ISPs (Internet Service Providers) and Hosters, as well as IT staff within companies DO block outgoing TCP Port 1433 due to the [SQL Slammer worm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Slammer). This outgoing port blocking appears to be one of the most faced issues of newcommers to SQL Azure.

**UPDATE Nov. 2015**

As of August 2015, there is preview feature that enables you to use Azure AD to authenticate to Azure SQL Database. You can read more on this new preview feature here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-aad-authentication/

Comment: Thank you very much astaykov for your considered response. I believe that the ISP has TCP Port 1433 blocked for the reasons you have stated. I will follow up with them and find out if this is the case.

Comment: As you outlined, once I had the ISP unlock the port, everything worked fine. Many thanks.

Comment: how to "Explicitly chose to not trust server certificate in connection string"?  SQL server management studio does not have this option

Comment: @Cherven if you connect via visual studio you can go to advanced and change it there

Comment: @jtromans how do i know if my ISP has blocked the tcp port 1433?

Comment: @GMan, by calling The support and asking

Comment: You can try accessing the same port on a host that you know is open. Otherwise, calling is reasonable.

Comment: @GMan http://portquiz.net:1433/ <-- if you can reach that page then your port is not being blocked.

Comment: @astaykov, what if I have sql server set on on premise? I mean I want to connect on premise sql server with Azure AI Search but connection string is giving me error.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using corporate network for internet access and facing this problem,
a simple way around this is to use your phone's mobile hotspot for internet access instead.

Be sure to disable your ethernet connection too, which may also be connected to the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Spent hours on this issue.  The fix for me was finally found to be my setting on the Xfinity firewall.  I had it set to high.  Once I changed the setting to low security, I could connect to the Azure sql database with no issues.