# Access denied after Azure publish

Tags: sql-server, azure

I am connecting to a SQL server in my web app, which works perfectly when debugging in VS.

However, after publishing to Azure I am seeing

> Access is denied

Connection string:

```
<add name="ADVWKSP01" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.ADVWKSP01.csdl|res://*/Models.ADVWKSP01.ssdl|res://*/Models.ADVWKSP01.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=SERVERNAME;initial catalog=ADVWKSP01;persist security info=True;user id=sql_user;password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
```

I also tried setting the connection string in azure portal with

```
metadata=res://*/Models.ADVWKSP01.csdl|res://*/Models.ADVWKSP01.ssdl|res://*/Models.ADVWKSP01.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=sgazrstgsql04v;initial catalog=ADVWKSP01;persist security info=True;user id=sql_user;password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework'
```

But with the same result.

How is this even possible? Why would my local machine be allowed to connect, but not an app on Azure?

I also tried logging in using my Microsoft credentials (which apparently have access) but I get this annoying message in VS when creating the EF connection:

[image]

Can someone please advise how I can troubleshoot this issue?

Full error message:

```
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied]

[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling) +999
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +800
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +739
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +85
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +449
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.WaitForPendingOpen() +344
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +61
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<<ExecuteAsync>b__3>d__6.MoveNext() +226
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +61
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<ExecuteAsyncImplementation>d__9`1.MoveNext() +355
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +61
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.<OpenAsync>d__8.MoveNext() +593

[EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open.]
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.<OpenAsync>d__8.MoveNext() +670
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +61
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<EnsureConnectionAsync>d__9.MoveNext() +444
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +61
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<ExecuteInTransactionAsync>d__3d`1.MoveNext() +259
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +61
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<ExecuteAsyncImplementation>d__9`1.MoveNext() +364
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +61
   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() +59
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<GetResultsAsync>d__e.MoveNext() +638
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +61
   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() +59
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.<FirstMoveNextAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +259
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +61
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.<ForEachAsync>d__5`1.MoveNext() +357
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +61
   ADVWKSP.Controllers.<Index>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Bassie\source\repos\TFS\ADVWKSP\ADVWKSP\Controllers\CRMTItemsController.cs:92
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +61
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +228
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.InvokeEndHandler(IAsyncResult ar) +152
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +126
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why would my local machine be allowed to connect, but not an app on Azure?

When you connect in local machine, you may connect to the local sql database. While you publish to azure, you need to connect to the **azure sql database** which you may do not configure.

Windows Azure SQL Database (formerly known as SQL Azure) works exclusively and only on **TCP port 1433**.

In order to successfully establish connection to SQL Azure one must fulfil the following requirements:

1.Create SQL Azure server & Database

2.Setup SQL Azure Server's firewall rules to accept connections from the IP address of application that will connect to that server

3.Make sure the box (be it Virtual, or home, or whatever) has no blocking outbound TCP port 1433

4.Explicitly force encryption in connection string

5.Explicitly chose to not trust server certificate in connection string

For more detail, you could refer to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617687/cannot-connect-to-azure-sql-database-even-with-whitelisted-ip).

Also, you could refer to this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10085/troubleshooting-connectivity-issues-with-microsoft-azure-sql-database) to troubleshooting.

> I also tried logging in using my Microsoft credentials (which apparently have access) but I get this annoying message in VS when creating the EF connection

You could have Encrypt=false or add the following in the connection string:

```
TrustServerCertificate=True
```